# use closure as array value in config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a configuration file like this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

    return [
        'foo' => function() {
            return 1;
        },
        'date' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()
    ];
```

When calling `Config::get('file.foo')` it returns the following instead of the closure's return value. :

> ```
>  >>> Config::get('file.foo')
>  => Closure {#39
>       class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration",
>       this: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration {#33 …},
>       file: "/App/config/file.php",
>       line: "6 to 8",    }
> ```

But

```
Config::get('file.date');
```

returns

> ```
>   >>> Config::get('file.date')
>   => "2015-08-04"
> ```

Why is the call to a class method resolved but the closure isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**date** is resolved, because Carbon's **toDateString()** is executed in the config file. **foo** is not resolved, because you just assign a closure to **foo** so the value of **foo** is the closure. If you want **foo** to be equal to the value returned from the closure you'll need to execute the clojure.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is late but, as I just hit this question, this is what I've done:

```
    return [
        'foo' => (function() {
            return 1;
        })(),
        'date' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()
    ];
```

This will evaluate the closure on spot.